# Zend Framework 2: Accessing query parameter without params plugin / using params plugin outside of controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am writing a service that does some stuff with certain query parameter, their names are known.

Since I am not in a controller, I can't use the params plugin.

How can I access query parameters in Zend Framework 2 without using the params plugin? Is there a way to use the params plugin outside of a controller?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can get the query like:

```
$request = $this->getServiceManager()->get('Request');
$query = $request->getQuery();
```

More detailed example:

```
<?php

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface;

class SomeService implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface
{
    protected $serviceManager;

    public function getServiceManager()
    {
        return $this->serviceManager;
    }

    public function setServiceManager(ServiceManager $serviceManager)
    {
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
        return $this;
    }

    public function doSomething() 
    {
        $request = $this->getServiceManager()->get('Request');
        $query = $request->getQuery();

        // as well as:
        $params = $this->getServiceManager()->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('params');
    }
}
```

Comment: Vasil Dakov's detailed example could be simplified with a trait: `class Class1
{
  use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;
}`

Comment: I think I understood now how it works. Inside my service, I am now using the ServiceManager & ServiceManagerAwareInterface. As soon as I get my service in another module's controller using `$something = $serviceLocator->get('MyService');`, I see a white page. From the error log: `rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php"`. I know it's a bit vague to ask, but do you have *any idea*  what is happening there?